# How to add error sound in PHP using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Need to know how to add a small error sound in PHP when a user enters a wrong password. Below is code being used.I know I have to use js or jquery to play the sound and was hoping if someone could help me with this.Thanks in Advance.

```
<?php
    include "header.php";

    if (isset($_GET['loginFailed'])) {
        $message = "Invalid Credentials ! Please try again.";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin_login_style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>


<body>
    <form action="./admin_login_action.php" method="post">
        <div class="flex-container-1">
            <div class="flex-item">
                <h2>Administrator Login</h2>
            </div>

            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <div class="flex-item">
                <input type="text" name="admin_uname" required>
            </div>

            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <div class="flex-item">
                <input type="password" name="admin_psw" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-container-2">
            <div class="flex-item">
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-item">
                <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your error sound mp3 file?. just play error mp3 file instead of alert.

Comment: Hi Sorry I'm new to this, could you explain how to import the file and play

Answer (score 0):

Because of security purpose, The Chrome or some modern browsers does not play the sound automatically without user interaction.

The following alert message arise in Console if we try to play the sound on page load.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user
> didn't interact with the document first. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

You can play a sound with some interaction using the following 2 methods that i found to be the best ones among others.

**Using Default HTML+JS Method:**

```
<audio id="my_audio" src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3724.mp3" loop="loop"></audio>
document.getElementById("my_audio").play(); // Using JS
// $("#my_audio").get(0).play(); // Using jQuery
```

**Using jQuery playSound library:**

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound/master/jquery.playSound.js'></script>
<script>
$.playSound("http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3724.mp3");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to echo html audio tag on error...

```
if (isset($_GET['loginFailed'])) {
        $message = "Invalid Credentials ! Please try again.";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        echo '<audio autoplay><source src="error.mp3"></audio>';  
    }
```

The only drawback is that browsers these days will ask the user to allow autoplay sounds.Like stated on the other answer.